# Issues changing from wildcard to explicit app ID

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, in-house-distribution

I have an iOS app with four targets (iOS App, WatchKit App, WatchKit Extension, custom framework), that I want to publish for in-house usage.

Since wildcard app IDs cannot be used for in-house apps, I created four new explicit App IDs.
I also created four new provisioning profiles, where I selected the "In House" option and the new App IDs.

Then I downloaded the new provisioning profiles to XCode and configured them in my Build Settings, for each target.
I also already executed the Clean-task, deleted my Derived Data-folder and deleted / re-downloaded all provisioning profiles multiple times.

The problem is: I still get the error

> "Wildcard App IDs cannot be used to create In House provisioning profiles. Please use an Explicit App ID."

when I click the `Upload to App Store` button or try to export the archive.

What am I missing here or what else can I try?
Please ask if you need any further information or clarification.

(I already [posted](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26724) this in the Apple developer forums. But since it got very few views and no answers there, I decided to crosspost.)

Comment: Have you verified that the embedded.mobileprovision file in the .app are correct?  If not, you have a build settings problem.  do a show contents on the .app and verify the mobileprovision file by opening it in TextEdit.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I checked them all, the app IDs in the mobileprovision-files are correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't ever seen an issue like this.  I would open a ticket with Apple support to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message about Wildcard App IDs when trying to export.

When searching for a solution I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35400712 about Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority certificate being expired.

Checking my certificate and seeing it was expired I followed the directions and downloaded a new certificate: https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer.

After removing the old certificate I was able to proceed with the export.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by importing another provisioning profile for development, in addition to the one I had imported before for release.

Comment: Its not elated to the mobile provisioning. specially development provisioning is not used to archive the product.