# This certificate has an invalid issuer Apple Push Services

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate, keychain

I have created certificate to enable Push Services in my app, but every time I try to add certificate in my Keychain, after adding certificate it shows me following error:

**This certificate has an invalid issuer**

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/35406327/5512225

Comment: Note to people voting to close:  This is on-tropic because it is about a TOOL that PROGRAMMERS use.

Comment: Readers should note that this problem is not specific for Push Services, but is found equally for expired iOS and Mac Developer and Distribution certificates. (The solutions work equally well for these.)

Comment: Congrats on most relevant question, this Q is linked to by industry-standard CI tool for iOS fastlane during the step for downloading code signing identities called Match.

Answer (score 628):

I think I've figured this one out. I imported the [new WWDR Certificate that expires in 2023](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer), but I was still getting problems building and my developer certificates were still showing the invalid issuer error.

- In keychain access, go to *View* -> *Show Expired Certificates*. Then in your login keychain highlight the expired WWDR Certificate and delete it.
- I also had the same expired certificate in my System keychain, so I deleted it from there too (important).

After deleting the expired certificate from the login and System keychains, I was able to build for Distribution again.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me as well. It is important to remove the expired certificate from both the login and System keychains.

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly for me. Once I enabled Show expired certificates, there were login and system certs which expired today - February 14, 2016. I was able to delete them and add the WWDR cert from your link. After that it worked perfectly!

Comment: Had followed previous advise to delete based on 'Show Expired Certificates', but had only done Login. Also deleting from System did the trick.

Comment: please note, that you need to remove it also from System as well

Comment: For me, I already had the new certificate (that expires in 2023), but I also had the old one that had expired.  Both were in my System keychain.  Once I removed the old certificate, I was able to build using my Distribution cert.

Comment: It was the system thing that did it for me too. Apple really screwed up here - without SO there would simply be no way of finding this answer.

Comment: Deleting expired certificate from System is rather most important.

Comment: Maybe worthwhile to note that there is a similar bug in Keychain in which exporting p12 of an item will export the old expired one, unless you delete your old one. If you don't believe it verify with a Java or Python p12 reader.

Comment: I got stuck where I should have removed the old certificate - couldn't do it due to UNIX permissions error - and this thread just saved my life: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511314/unable-to-delete-apple-wwdrc-certificate?noredirect=1#comment58849071_35511314

Comment: The full name of the expired certificate you're looking for is "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority.

Comment: followed your steps, did not work... After reboot my mac, It worked.Thank you

Comment: Important to note that "Show expired Certificates" must be checked in the Menu in order to be able to see the ones that need to be deleted

Comment: I was frustrated for a whole friggin' day and turned out I only have to delete one expired certificate. Really nice.

Comment: This answer helped me, but I wasn't seeing the problem from the Keychain Access app, but from the CI build that uses the security cmd. When CI imported a certificate and tried to use "system find-identity -v keychain" it reported 0 valid identities. Without the "-v" option, it showed the identity, but with a suffix: CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED. That initially made us think the cert had expired, but it had not. It wasn't until I tried manually adding the cert to the keychain on the failing machine that we saw that the issuer had expired. Hopefully, this comment helps someone in the same situation.

Comment: For me it worked right after installing new WWDR Certificate that expires in 2023. Thanks!

Answer (score 255):

1. Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer
   and double-click to install to Keychain.
2. Select "View" -> "Show Expired Certificates" in Keychain app.
3. Confirm "Certificates" category is selected.

   [image]
4. Remove expired Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority certificates from "login" tab and "System" tab.

---

Here's Apple's answer.

> Thanks for bringing this to the attention of the community and apologies for the issues you’ve been having. This issue stems from having a copy of the expired WWDR Intermediate certificate in both your System and Login keychains. To resolve the issue, you should first download and install the new WWDR intermediate certificate (by double-clicking on the file). Next, in the Keychain Access application, select the System keychain. Make sure to select “Show Expired Certificates” in the View menu and then delete the expired version of the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority Intermediate certificate (expired on February 14, 2016). Your certificates should now appear as valid in Keychain Access and be available to Xcode for submissions to the App Store.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/37208

Comment: Deleting expired Apple Worldwide Developer cert from key chain only helps but some times keychain does not show up you have quit and open key chain then search again Apple Worldwide Developer and make sure you should be selecting Allkeys. It took hell lot of time to fix this because expired Apple Worldwide Developer cert was still appearing after many deletions.

Comment: Do I need to export the apple push service certificate newly after doing these above steps and upload them in my server? suddenly push notifications are not working.

Comment: I got stuck in the part where I should have removed the old certificate - couldn't do it due to UNIX permissions error - and this thread just saved my life: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511314/unable-to-delete-apple-wwdrc-certificate?noredirect=1#comment58849071_35511314

Answer (score 162):

This is not actually a development issue. It happens due to expiration of the **Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate** issued by **Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority**. WWDRCA issues the certificate to sign your software for Apple devices, allowing our systems to confirm that your software is delivered to users as intended and has not been modified.

To resolve this issue, you have to follow the below steps:

1. Open Keychain Access
2. Go to **View** -> **Show Expired Certificates**

[image]

3. Go to **System** in Keychain
   [image]
4. Here you find that "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority" is marked as expired. So delete it. Also check under Login Tab and delete expired WWDRCA.
5. Download new [WWDR Intermediate Certificate](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer) from here(The renewed Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Intermediate Certificate will expire on February 7, 2023).
6. Install it by double clicking on it.

If you still face any issue with your iOS apps, Mac apps, Safari extensions, Apple Wallet and Safari push notifications, then please follow [this link of expiration](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/).

> The Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Intermediate
>   Certificate expires soon and we've issued a renewed certificate that
>   must be included when signing all new Apple Wallet Passes, push
>   packages for Safari Push Notifications, and Safari Extensions starting
>   February 14, 2016.
>
> While most developers and users will not be affected by the
>   certificate change, we recommend that all developers download and
>   install the renewed certificate on their development systems and
>   servers as a best practice. All apps will remain available on the App
>   Store for iOS, Mac, and Apple TV.

Comment: need to ensure that its really get deleted..now worked. Thanks.

Comment: That's funny. I had problems with that certificate too, but in a other way

Comment: I got stuck trying to remove the old certificate - couldn't do it due to UNIX permissions error - and this thread just saved my life: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511314/unable-to-delete-apple-wwdrc-certificate?noredirect=1#comment58849071_35511314

Comment: How would I ensure this step is taken care of if I am to run a macOS runner using Github actions workflow?

Answer (score 101):

Here is how we fixed this.

Step 1: Open Keychain access, delete "Apple world wide Developer relations certification authority" (which expires on 14th Feb 2016) from both "**Login**" and "**System**" sections.
If you can't find it, use “Show Expired Certificates” in the View menu.

Step 2: Download [this](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer) and add it to *Keychain access* -> *Certificates*
(which expires on 8th Feb 2023).

Step 3: Everything should be back to normal and working now.

Reference: [Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate Expiration](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/)

Comment: I got stuck where I should have removed the old certificate - couldn't do it due to UNIX permissions error - and this thread just saved my life: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511314/unable-to-delete-apple-wwdrc-certificate?noredirect=1#comment58849071_35511314

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. Before deleting that cert, I had Reset buttons in Xcode Accounts next to my signing identities, but pressing them did nothing. After deleting the expired "Apple world wide Developer relations certification authority" certificate, I was able to press Reset on each item in Xcode and it cleared it (the Reset button went away). On a side note...my god Apple, can you not make this stuff work better? I swear tens of thousands of hours of developer time have been wasted on these insane certificate/profile/signing issues...just make it work!!

Comment: How would I ensure this step is taken care of if I am to run a macOS runner using Github actions workflow?

Answer (score 38):

In Apple's Developer's portal, add a new certificate, and when asked "What type of certificate do you need?" choose "WorldWide developer relations certificate". Generate the new certificate, download and install. The moment you do that, you will no longer see the message you have described.

**Edit:**
The certificate can be downloaded from the following page:
https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/
You can choose one of the following two certificates:
"WWDR Certificate (Expiring 02/07/23)"
or
"WWDR Certificate (Expiring 02/14/16)"

Comment: there is no such option appears when we add new certificate

Comment: downloaded and installed the new cert but still having the same issue - anything else have to do?

Comment: @MrZorn I'm having the same problem, but just FYI I tried to export the p12 and it worked anyway.

Comment: @MrZorn U need to go View -> show expried -> del the old WWDR cert

Comment: How would I ensure this step is taken care of if I am to run a macOS runner using Github actions workflow?

Answer (score 32):

Follow the below steps:

1. Download and install from [here](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer). Double click and install it.
2. Select "View" -> "Show Expired Certificates" in Keychain app.
3. Remove Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority
   certificates from "login" tab and "System" tab in Keychain app.

If you don't find your WWDR certificate in **Login** or **System** tab, then select category "**All items**" on the left side. Most probably you will get to see an expired WWDR certificate here, and you can remove it. An expired certificate is always shown with a red asterisk.

Comment: How would I ensure this step is taken care of if I am to run a macOS runner using Github actions workflow?

Answer (score 28):

If you are facing the "This certificate has an invalid issuer" error for all your certificates then do the following steps.

**Steps:**

- Open Keychain and Click on Login -> All Items from the left panel.
- Now, Click on *View* -> *Show Expired Certificates* from the top navigation menu.
- Now search for "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" and delete expired certificates. [image]
- After deleting expired certificates, visit the following URL and download the new certificate,
  https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer.
- Double click on the newly downloaded certificate, and install it in your keychain.
- Double check: List expired certificates by following step number 3.
- Now you have a valid "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" having expiry date 2023-02-07.

**Reference:**

- *[Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate Expiration](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/)*

Comment: How would I ensure this step is taken care of if I am to run a macOS runner using Github actions workflow?

Answer (score 23):

As described in the [Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate Expiration](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/):

---

The previous Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Intermediate Certificate expired on **February 14, 2016** and the renewed certificate must now be used when signing Apple Wallet Passes, push packages for Safari Push Notifications, Safari Extensions, and submissions to the App Store, Mac App Store, and App Store for Apple TV.

All developers should download and install the [renewed certificate](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer) on their development systems and servers. All apps will remain available on the App Store for iOS, Mac, and Apple TV.

---

**The new valid certificate will look like the following:**

[image: Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority]

It will display (this certificate is valid) with a green mark.

So, **go to your Key Chain Access**. Just **delete the old certificate** and replace it with the new one ([renewed certificate](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer)) as Apple described in the document. Mainly the problem is only with the Apple push notification service and extensions as described in the Apple document.

You can also check the listing of certificates in https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

Certificate Revocation List:

[image: Certificate Revocation List]

Now this updated certificate will expire on 2023-02-08.

---

If you could not see the old certificate then go to the **System Keychains** and from edit menu and select the option *Show Expired Certificates*.

[image: Show Expired Certificates]

Now you can see the following certificate that you have to delete:

[image: Delete This Certificate]

Comment: How would I ensure this step is taken care of if I am to run a macOS runner using Github actions workflow?

Answer (score 20):

You need to search the **World** from the top right search bar and delete the expired certificate. Make sure you selected **Login** and **All items**.

[image]

Comment: How would I ensure this step is taken care of if I am to run a macOS runner using Github actions workflow?

Answer (score 16):

Just try to set local date earlier than Feb 14. Works for me! Not a complete solution but temporary solve the problem.

Comment: Like you said, this is not a solution. But it's still interesting, that why I won't downvote.

Answer (score 7):

If you got here from the Fastlane then this snippet might fix your CI deployments. Execute it before the signing.

```rb
 apple_intermediate_certificate_path = "/tmp/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer"
`curl https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer --output #{apple_intermediate_certificate_path}`

other_action.import_certificate(
  certificate_path: apple_intermediate_certificate_path,
  keychain_name: YOUR_KEYCHAIN_NAME,
  keychain_password: YOUR_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD
)
```

Comment: I get this error on import_certificate. 
`security: SecKeychainItemImport: Write permissions error.`
and getting the same error on get_certificate: `Could not create another Distribution certificate, reached the maximum number of available Distribution certificates`
@Cyril any thoughts?

Comment: Hi @adee, do you have the keychain unlocked? You can have a look here; https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/unlock_keychain/. In my case, I always create a new keychain and I never experienced such errors. Maybe you can try something like that.

Answer (score 6):

- All my certificates are installed and expire dates are fine.
- I deleted and reinstalled all my certificates, still no luck

In the end, I right-clicked on the certificate, and selected "Get Info". Under the Trust section, I selected "Always Trust" and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**in 2021:**

1. Download **AppleWWDRCAG3.cer** (valid untill 2030) from
   https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/
2. Install it

Answer (score 0):

If you are here from `fastlane` suggestion and still getting this error

- after trying all above fixes
- `security find-identity -v -p codesigning` returns `valid identities found`
- error is happening only on build server
- if you log in "manually" everything works

then this is probably due to the fact that the distribution certificate is in the wrong place:

- "Login" keychain works while logged in
- "System" keychain works with build server run as daemon

Check [this answer with screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60111046/1463086), you can just right click distribution certificate in the login keychain and paste it into system.