# This certificate has an invalid issuer : Keychain marks all certificates as "Invalid Issuer"

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, ssl-certificate, keychain

Keychain shows all the certificates as Invalid in my keychain suddenly, as it working before 2 days and i also check in Developer portal and it shows valid there. It marks each and every certificate in Keychain as **"This certificate has invalid issuer"** . As message suggesting that it must be problem from issuer side and and our issuer is Apple. So how to fix it ?

This certificate has an invalid issuer

Here i posting image of keychain. I need quick help.

[image]

Comment: check this thread may be helpful for you. https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/45siza/this_certificate_has_an_invalid_issuer/

Comment: check this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services

Comment: It works after reinstalling AppleWWDRCA. Thanks

Comment: Here is answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35457959/1961064

Comment: http://bit.ly/1QEU9XW: See this one to solve issue.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

In Keychain access, 
 -> View -> Show Expired Certificates, then in your login keychain click on expired certificate and delete it. I also had the same expired certificate in my System keychain, so I deleted it from there too.

-> After deleting the expired cert from the login and System keychains,download certificate from below link and open with keychain.

Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and add it to Keychain access > certificates (which expires on 2023)

Comment: I found it in the System Keychain, not in the Login keychain. Thanks anyway!

Comment: after installing new wwdrca certificate "This certificate has an invalid issuer" is not gone

Comment: Once remove certificates which are showing Invalid issuer and try again by installing

Comment: This was preventing me from submitting  to Apple an version... And all Xcode gived me was some non-related error.... Updating AppleWWDRCA on system keychain solved!

Comment: Worth adding: if you have BOTH the old certificate and the new one, it still may fail, so do remember to delete the old one

Comment: Need to remove the old one

Comment: this issue was preventing me from making an enterprise build to export, never did Xcode say that this was the issue. I happened to notice the red text, used this fix, and voila...!

Comment: If I remove certificates they just auto-reappar.

Comment: @JohnyTex if that is the case, then you are probably removing them from Login keychain and not the System one. I noticed the same behavior if I didn't delete from the System keychain.

Comment: This got rid of the "invalid issuer" problems. Searched "devel" and deleted anything expired. This didn't solve my problem of not being able to deploy a test build to my phone. When is Apple going to finally make it easy to run my own code on my own phone?