# Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for App

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode7, ad-hoc-distribution

I am creating archive for Ad-hoc development. I created all the certificates and integrated into Xcode. But I get warning. Check attached image.[image]

I also installed AppleWWDRCA.cer and AppleWWDRCAG2.cer certificates. But I am still facing the same problem.

I referred following link but getting same problem again and again.

[Xcode 7 error: "Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821189/xcode-7-error-missing-ios-distribution-signing-identity-for)

Comment: Have u deleted the invalid certificates . Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35403096/5362916

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Keychain Search for

> Apple world wide Developer relations certification authority

Delete this.

2. Download https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer and add it to Keychain access > certificates