# Apple Certificate for iOS Developer and Mac Developer is expired "The certificate has an invalid issuer"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, keychain

**The certificate has an invalid issuer**

**Apple Certificate for IOS and Mac is not working all show they are expired but they not expired.**

[image]

Comment: My error is not just Expired, My error is The certificate has an invalid issuer, It is not some problem

Comment: Please follow this link , here i explain all steps to resolve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/error-this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-using-apple-push-services/35409835#35409835

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For first you need clean you keychain.

Remove "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" from all places. from **System** and **Login** tab

[image]

Download from apple.com [Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer)

Double-click to [AppleWWDRCA.cer](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer)  install to Keychain.

Also, ensure that Keychain is showing expired certificates: Keychain > View > Show Expired Certificates

Enjoy !! :)

Comment: Also, ensure that Keychain is showing expired certificates: Keychain > View > Show Expired Certificates.

Comment: Let me edit question, thanks for update