# ERROR ITMS-90292: "Invalid Provisioning Profile Signature"

Tags: xcode, macos

Hi I wanted to submit an update to the Mac App Store today and got the following error message:

[image]

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue,

How I fixed it was instead of selecting my normal automatic manage signing. I selected manually manage signing

[image: Manually Manage Signin]

Then click on the distribution certificate dropdown, followed by manage certificates...

[image: Certificate Selection]

Then you'll notice your current certificate is not in your keychain. You can add a new one with the add button on the bottom left and it'll be your default certificate

Then once added. Click cancel on the manual signing, choose automatic signing again and it should upload.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to renew the certificate being used to sign the application. Search for "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" in Keychain, delete it and get a new certificate from https://developer.apple.com/account/mac/certificate/

Make sure you also updated the Apple certificates: [Apple Certificate for iOS Developer and Mac Developer is expired "The certificate has an invalid issuer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457958/apple-certificate-for-ios-developer-and-mac-developer-is-expired-the-certificat)

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to close Xcode, and delete all files in this folder:

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
```

When done, restart Xcode and retry to upload or validate your archive.