# How to solve missing ios distribution signing identity

Tags: ios, xcode

I tried to install WWDR intermediate certificate, but it shows "The “System Roots” keychain cannot be modified"

Comment: You can download the certificate and directly double click on that certificate. It automatically installs.You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35403096/5362916

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try this steps:

- Open your Keychain Access
- On the left side you will see 'Login' ,'System' and 'System Roots'
- Now drag your certificate in 'Login' option
- You will get certificate install successfully in Keychain Access

Hope it will help you.