# Trying to validate archive in Xcode - What certificate is missing?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

Since I last distributed an app on App Store, I have changed Mac.
(When doing so, I automatically moved all files from the old to the new one)

When I now try to validate an archive prior send to appStore,
I get this annoying message

["Missing  iOs distribution signing identity for (my name)" Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4DbC.png)
I have checked all provisioning profiles and they seem to be there.

Question is: Should I have exported the developer profile from old Xcode on old Mac and import on new Mac even though I moved over all old files?

Preferences in Xcode looks like this.
[Where is says "ios develoment" and "ios distribution" there is a button saying "reset" See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zh2w.png)

**I guess "reset" means I am still lacking something although I have been dowloading all profiles needed to take me this far in the signing routine?**

Please help if you can. I have been spending so much time with this.
(I have access to olf Mac, still, but it is some distance away)

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the appropriate certificate and private key in your keychain. Those may need to be exported as a p12 from the keychain of the original Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you copied over the provisioning profile and possibly even the cert from the old Mac (or downloaded them from the Apple developer site.  Those 2 things are only 2 of the 3 pieces.  You need the private key that goes with the certificate.  That piece is not available from the Apple dev site, because if Apple did have it, they would be able to build and sign apps as if they were you, which they do not want to have the ability to do.

To rectify this, you can either get the key off of the old Mac, or do a reset (which will revoke your old cert, generate a new private key on your new mac, make a new cert and provisioning profiles).

To get the key, go to the old Mac, and open the Keychain Access app.  Find the certificate you use for iOS development and iOS distribution.  You should be able to expand the cert (a little triangle next to it).  When expanded, it will show you the key that is associated with the cert.  You can export it from Keychain, copy it to the new Mac, and your certs and provisioning profiles should then work (make sure you restart Xcode after doing all this before trying to build).

If you no longer plan on doing builds on the old Mac, or if you no longer have access to it, I would simply do a reset and you should be good to go on the new Mac.

Comment: HI and thanks so much for your answer, I learnt much from it.

Comment: Sorry I meant to add this to the above comment:

However, I have downloaded new keys and have tried again but still with the same result, that Xcode wont let me validate the archive.

I have created new distribution- and development keys.
I have deleted old certificates.

I have created a new provisioning profile and I have bult the app again (Appcelerator)
Still no success to validate.

Do I need to create a new app id too and from that do the provisioning profile based on that?

What things do I need in my keychain to make this work?
I thought I had it all now.

Comment: You should not need a new app ID.  When you go into the Keychain Access app, can you expand the cert and see a key under it?  Also, when you click on the cert, does it show a green check and state that it is valid.  Also, make sure you've deleted any old provisioning profiles in the ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles directory.

Answer (score 0):

and thanks so much for qualified answers.
After deleting old certificates I finally understood that this all was due to the known problem with the AppleWWDRCA that needed some attention.
I had allready downloaded and installed that, hence I  didn't think that was the issue.

But cleaning up and deleting old certificates and downloading that file again did the trick finally.
[So I did like it says here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402862/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-keychain-marks-all-certificates-as-inv)

Thank again for guiding me through the certificates and key universe ;-)