# Expired WWDR certificate and Safari Extension Builder

Tags: macos, safari, keychain, safari-extension

Today, Apple's WWDR certificate expired. I've removed it from Keychain Access, both from `login` and `system`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services). I've also downloaded and imported a new version of WWDR certificate.

However, when I open Safari Extension Builder and create/add an extension, the old WWDR certificate gets back to Keychain Access and I see "No Safari Extensions Certificate" warning in Extension Builder. I made sure I have a valid Safari certificate in Keychain.

How do I delete expired WWDR certificate completely so it doesn't appear again when I work on Safari extensions? I've tried removing Safari folder from Library directory and restarting my Mac, but it didn't help.

Comment: Same here :( Deleting cert from Keychain also gives nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in El Capitan v10.11.4 beta 3.

Comment: is there any way of working around this without installing the beta OS X?

Comment: @mix you can install Safari 9.1 beta