# Apple’s World Wide Developer Relations (WWDR) intermediate certificate is not installed

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am not able to publish my app (AdHoc) via Appcelerator Titanium today, I started to get this error:

> [ERROR] :  Apple’s World Wide Developer Relations (WWDR) intermediate certificate >is not installed.
>
> [ERROR] :  This will prevent you from building apps for iOS devices or package >for distribution.

I checked online and installed the required certificates and even restarted the mac, I still can't build. This is my keychain entries:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This certificate has an invalid issuer Apple Push Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit me today as well. 
See this thread: [This certificate has an invalid issuer Apple Push Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services)

(I am not using push notifications at all. This expired cert broke my ability to code-sign "vanilla" apps with no special entitlements.)

You need to find the expired cert in your keychain, delete it, and download a new one.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this out when I'm home.

Answer (score 4):

Simplly you can do it

1. First Open KeyChain access,Delete "Apple world wide Developer relations
   certification authority" (WWDR) (Which expires on 14th Feb 2016) from both
   "Login" and "System" sections. If you can't find it, then go to **View** > **Show Expired Certificates** in the menu.
2. then go to [Apple WWDR](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/) and download new certificate and install.