# Cert not finding existing certificates

Tags: fastlane

I am calling cert in this way.

```
cert create \
    --development \
    --username 'myusername@email.com' \
    --team_id 'MYTEAMID123' \
    --output_path '/This/Is/My/Path/_Certificates/PathPath/Development'
```

In 1.2.3 with this same call I got the following output:

```
[12:29:31]: Starting login with user 'myusername@email.com'
[12:29:32]: Successfully logged in
[12:29:34]: Certificate ABC123 (Jon Doe) can't be found on your local computer
[12:29:35]: Found the certificate ABC12345 (Jack Doe) which is installed on the local machine. Using this one.
```

Then the certificate would be downloaded and placed in the output path tha I have specified.

**I am on 1.3.0 now and it fails to find any of my certificates that are installed.**

I do unlock my keychain earlier in my scripts with:

```
/usr/bin/security list-keychains -s '/Users/.../login.keychain'
/usr/bin/security default-keychain -d user -s '/Users/.../login.keychain'
/usr/bin/security unlock-keychain -p JONDOE '/Users/.../login.keychain'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am dumb. I found the closed [issue](https://github.com/fastlane/cert/issues/66) for [cert](https://github.com/fastlane/cert).

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services) and it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: For posterity, could you include the relevant parts of the link which you found useful in your answer? That way, if the link goes down, changes, etc., your answer won't be rendered useless. Many thanks.