# cannot distribute for adhoc, WWDR is current

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

Just a couple of days ago everything was perfect, now when I try to build for ad hoc distribution I get this:

[image]

Also it adds 3 profiles XC Ad Hoc:... each time I try, and it keeps growing:

[image]

I checked all my certificates etc nothing changed, besides that stupid XC Ad Hoc profile duplicates being added.

Anybody have a clue wth going on?

Comment: In Keychain, the WWDR Certificate expired a few days back. Delete it, and download it again (a little search should be enough). Delete it in your Mac System, not only on your session and all your certifications should be trusted again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This certificate has an invalid issuer Apple Push Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services)

Comment: I do not have that WWDR at all, all other certs are up to date

Comment: You checked in KeyChain.app ?

Comment: yeap, i did not have it. I just added it - did not help, same story.