# Can't Delete Expired Apple Developer Certificate

Tags: xcode, safari

I've followed the instructions described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services) to get my certificate renewed (Apple's certificate debacle from earlier this year).

Problem: Every time I restart Safari's Extension Builder, it adds the expired certificate back.[image]

In the Extension Builder, it says "No Safari Extension Certificate"

Comment: Look at your Keychain Access, and check the System Keychain.  Make sure the old one is deleted there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue turned out to be with Apple. See answer

Comment: Madness.  Glad you solved it, but what a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem lies with Apple: https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

The issue was that when I tried to delete the certificate, it would come back every time we tried to rebuild the extension. Had to install OS X El Capitan v10.11.4+ beta to resolve this.