# XCode - No Provisioning profiles matching an applicable Signing identity were found

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to XCode and i am using XCode 7.3 version. I would like to run the app using the XCode on an iOS device. Here my iOS device is an IPAD. For this i have connected the IPAD device to the Mac book pro. The device has been recognized and it is shown in the list of Devices.

When i try to run the project via XCode in Mac connecting to the IPAD device,i am getting the error as "No Provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found" with a "Fix Issue" button.

When the Fix issue button is clicked, it tried to resolve the code signing issues and finally an error "An App ID with identifier 'XXX.XXXX.XXX' is not available. Please enter a different string" got displayed

I have a valid certificate and also the provisioning profiles downloaded onto my Mac which was created in the apple developer account. I tried a lot in fixing the issue but could not be able to fix it.

Can someone provide me a solution in order to fix this issue and run the app in iOS device?

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I am facing the same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct bundle identifier for your app, which is used to generate the provisioning profile.

3 things you need to check
1.Certificate 
2.Provisioning profile 
3.Bundle identifier

Also check the identifier you are giving must be there in your apple developer account 
In your case you might using wrong identifier in your info.plist 
Please check this for all targets

[image]

[image]

If everything is fine then also check the expired certificate in your keychain 
similar to this question 
[This certificate has an invalid issuer Apple Push Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services)

Comment: do you have test target? please check there too, also does your profile generated which the same certificate you using , if still face problem re-download the profile, also delete duplicate profile if any already there

Comment: I have cross checked whether the identifier in the info.plist is the same as the identifier in apple developer account. No issues with the identifier. Is there anything that needs to be verified? I have a valid certificate and a provisioning profile downloaded from the apple developer website. As i am a beginner, can you provide the steps from the scratch in detail on how to run the app via XCode on an iOS device?

Comment: I have verified and found that there are no test targets . How can we check whether the profile has been generated using the same certificate?  Can you tell me how to associate a profile to a certificate?

Comment: Do 1 thing if you are not sure then revoke the certificate and create again and update the provisioning profile

Comment: I have already done this earlier and failed in all my attempts in various ways... Revoked the existing certificate, created a CSR file, generated a new iOS development certificate, installed the certificate in Mac and connected the mac to iOS device and run the app but failed due to the error "No Provisioning profiles matching an applicable signing identity were found"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services   check this might be happening at your end I am not sure but please cross check your keychani