# Xcode Push Notifications Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications

I'm currently trying to enable my Push Notification on my project but I'm getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDZsO.png)

I went to my app ID and saw that it is enabled as well.

When I was looking at my certificated, I also saw that I'm getting a "this certificate has an invalid issuer" on my [certificated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUfbV.png) that I created. Could that be the main source of the problem?

I would appreciate any insight and thanks in advance! :)

Comment: For certificate problem, you may check the answer in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services

Comment: I tried doing the show expired certificates but it didn't seem to be the problem. I also tried downloading the file from the provided links but when I try to ran it, nothing happened. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Download this certificate and add inside your keychain

But first close your Xcode because it accessing your certificates thats why and delete all expire or invalid certificate from your keychain and restart your MAC then download this certificate and add into your keychain.

https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

I hope it will help you.

Comment: hm it still appears as "invalid issuer"

Comment: Actually i also faced Invalid certificate issue and i did this only. Have you deleted your all old certificate from your keychain?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by old certificate? All my certificates either say that it is valid or from an invalid issuer. None of them have actually expired :-(

Comment: Old certificate here those certificates you downloaded before and they were inside your KeyChain.Clear your all certificates from your keychain then restart your PC then install WWDRCA certificate.

Comment: i deleted all of my certificates and restarted my mac but when i double click the certificate in my downloads folder, my keychain access is popped up but nothing is downloaded into it :/

Comment: Have you tried to manually import certificate inside keychain? There options are available for import inside Keychain.If you having problem with import certificate with double click then you can go with this process.

Comment: hm i'm at a complete loss now. I tried going to File > import items > mycertificatefile but nothing shows up still. This is very strange

Comment: Ok let me check if any another way try to solve your problem if i get any type of solution related your issue.

Comment: i solved the problem! for some reason, the certificates just suddenly became validated out of nowhere. Don't really know how it happened but I think the credit goes to you :-) thank you Anand!

Comment: Well come  #Tim, now you understand how to resolve certificate issue Good job .