# iOS Code Signing Fastlane Match Error

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store-connect, code-signing, fastlane

I'm getting the following when trying to deploy my application to iTunes Connect using Fastlane.

It was working not too long ago, and I'm not sure why all the sudden it's now failing. I recently upgraded from CircleCI 1.0 to CircleCI 2.0, and that is about when it started to fail. The last deployment done on CircleCI 1.0 was successful, but everyone on CircleCI 2.0 has failed.

Any ideas how to fix this code signing error with Fastlane?

```
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|                        Summary for match 2.94.0                         |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| type                  | appstore                                        |
| app_identifier        | ["com.charliefish.ios.test"]             |
| force                 | true                                            |
| git_url               | https://github.com/fishcharlie/myprivatedataA.git |
| git_branch            | master                                          |
| username              | charlie@test.com                              |
| keychain_name         | login.keychain                                  |
| readonly              | false                                           |
| team_id               | 86LATJ1793                                      |
| verbose               | false                                           |
| skip_confirmation     | false                                           |
| shallow_clone         | false                                           |
| clone_branch_directly | false                                           |
| force_for_new_devices | false                                           |
| skip_docs             | false                                           |
| platform              | ios                                             |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+

[11:38:04]: Cloning remote git repo...
[11:38:04]: If cloning the repo takes too long, you can use the `clone_branch_directly` option in match.
[11:38:10]: Installing certificate...
security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
[11:38:11]: There are no local code signing identities found.
You can run `security find-identity -v -p codesigning` to get this output.
This Stack Overflow thread has more information: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35390072/774.
(Check in Keychain Access for an expired WWDR certificate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35409835/774 has more info.)

+-------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|                       Installed Certificate                        |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| User ID           | 86LATJ1793                                     |
| Common Name       | iPhone Distribution: Charlie Fish (86LATJ1793) |
| Organisation Unit | 86LATJ1793                                     |
| Organisation      | Charlie Fish                                   |
| Country           | US                                             |
| Start Datetime    | 2018-05-03 18:13:05 UTC                        |
| End Datetime      | 2019-05-03 18:13:05 UTC                        |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------+


+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|                               Summary for sigh 2.94.0                                |
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| app_identifier                      | com.charliefish.ios.test                |
| username                            | charlie@test.com                             |
| force                               | true                                           |
| cert_id                             | PQ8B8T1T54                                     |
| provisioning_name                   | match AppStore com.charliefish.ios.test |
| ignore_profiles_with_different_name | true                                           |
| team_id                             | 86LATJ1793                                     |
| platform                            | ios                                            |
| adhoc                               | false                                          |
| development                         | false                                          |
| skip_install                        | false                                          |
| skip_fetch_profiles                 | false                                          |
| skip_certificate_verification       | false                                          |
| readonly                            | false                                          |
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+

[11:38:12]: Starting login with user 'charlie@test.com'
[11:38:13]: Successfully logged in
[11:38:13]: Fetching profiles...
[11:38:14]: Verifying certificates...
[11:38:14]: There are no local code signing identities found.
You can run `security find-identity -v -p codesigning` to get this output.
This Stack Overflow thread has more information: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35390072/774.
(Check in Keychain Access for an expired WWDR certificate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35409835/774 has more info.)
[11:38:14]: Certificate for Provisioning Profile 'match AppStore com.charliefish.ios.test' not available locally: PQ8B8T1T54, skipping this one...
[11:38:14]: No existing profiles found, that match the certificates you have installed locally! Creating a new provisioning profile for you
[11:38:15]: There are no local code signing identities found.
You can run `security find-identity -v -p codesigning` to get this output.
This Stack Overflow thread has more information: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35390072/774.
(Check in Keychain Access for an expired WWDR certificate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35409835/774 has more info.)
[11:38:15]: No certificates for filter: Certificate ID: 'PQ8B8T1T54' 
+------------------+-------------+
|          Lane Context          |
+------------------+-------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios         |
| PLATFORM_NAME    | ios         |
| LANE_NAME        | ios release |
+------------------+-------------+
[11:38:15]: Could not find a matching code signing identity for type 'AppStore'. It is recommended to use match to manage code signing for you, more information on https://codesigning.guide. If you don't want to do so, you can also use cert to generate a new one: https://fastlane.tools/cert

+------+------------------+-------------+
|           fastlane summary            |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action           | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform | 0           |
|    | match            | 11          |
+------+------------------+-------------+

[11:38:15]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Could not find a matching code signing identity for type 'AppStore'. It is recommended to use match to manage code signing for you, more information on https://codesigning.guide. If you don't want to do so, you can also use cert to generate a new one: https://fastlane.tools/cert
```

**EDIT**

I'm now getting a different error after adding the setup CircleCI task in before all.

It looks like the repo is adding `.mobileprovision` to the end of profile. But it's searching for the non `.mobileprovision` version.

```
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|                        Summary for match 2.94.0                         |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| type                  | appstore                                        |
| app_identifier        | ["com.charliefish.ios.test"]             |
| force                 | true                                            |
| git_url               | https://github.com/fishcharlie/myprivatedataA.git |
| git_branch            | master                                          |
| username              | charlie@test.com                              |
| keychain_name         | fastlane_tmp_keychain                           |
| readonly              | true                                            |
| team_id               | 08RTYN1272                                      |
| verbose               | false                                           |
| skip_confirmation     | false                                           |
| shallow_clone         | false                                           |
| clone_branch_directly | false                                           |
| force_for_new_devices | false                                           |
| skip_docs             | false                                           |
| platform              | ios                                             |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------+

[14:04:47]: Cloning remote git repo...
[14:04:47]: If cloning the repo takes too long, you can use the `clone_branch_directly` option in match.
[14:04:48]:   Successfully decrypted certificates repo
[14:04:48]: Installing certificate...
security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
[14:04:49]: There are no local code signing identities found.
You can run `security find-identity -v -p codesigning` to get this output.
This Stack Overflow thread has more information: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35390072/774.
(Check in Keychain Access for an expired WWDR certificate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35409835/774 has more info.)

+-------------------+------------------------------------------------+
|                       Installed Certificate                        |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| User ID           | 08RTYN1272                                     |
| Common Name       | iPhone Distribution: Charlie Fish (08RTYN1272) |
| Organisation Unit | 08RTYN1272                                     |
| Organisation      | Charlie Fish                                   |
| Country           | US                                             |
| Start Datetime    | 2018-05-03 18:13:05 UTC                        |
| End Datetime      | 2019-05-03 18:13:05 UTC                        |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------+

[14:04:49]: No matching provisioning profiles found for 'AppStore_com.charliefish.ios.test'
[14:04:49]: A new one cannot be created because you enabled `readonly`
[14:04:49]: Provisioning profiles in your repo for type `appstore`:
[14:04:49]: - 'AppStore_com.charliefish.ios.test.mobileprovision'
[14:04:49]: If you are certain that a profile should exist, double-check the recent changes to your match repository
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    Lane Context                                    |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM          | ios                                                    |
| PLATFORM_NAME             | ios                                                    |
| LANE_NAME                 | ios release                                            |
| ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_KEYCHAIN | "/Users/distiller/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db" |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
[14:04:49]: No matching provisioning profiles found and can not create a new one because you enabled `readonly`. Check the output above for more information.

+------+----------------------------+-------------+
|                fastlane summary                 |
+------+----------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                     | Time (in s) |
+------+----------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | Verifying fastlane version | 0           |
| 2    | default_platform           | 0           |
| 3    | setup_circle_ci            | 0           |
|    | match                      | 2           |
+------+----------------------------+-------------+

[14:04:49]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] No matching provisioning profiles found and can not create a new one because you enabled `readonly`. Check the output above for more information.
```

Comment: Have you figured this issue?

Comment: @Georgy Just posted my answer that worked for me. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I've solved this issue by following the instructions in the blogpost: https://medium.com/sixt-labs-techblog/continuous-integration-and-delivery-at-sixt-91ca215670a0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by going back and looking at my v1.0 config. I had `read_only: false` set on my CI config. Which I don't think is the best practice. But it's now not throwing any errors and working fine. I'm pretty sure I'm still getting the warning `security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.`, but it's working even with that warning.

I do have the `setup_circle_ci` in my config also.

Answer (score 0):

This error can have a lot of reasons, some things you should try:

- Make sure you install certificate in local not in system.
- Check WWDR certificate Expiry date.
- Make sure to have a valid code signing identity defined in your project targets. This might happen when you select Don't Code Sign as Code Signing Identity.

I read your post in Upwork.