# Jenkins/fastlane - There are no local code signing identities found

Tags: ios, jenkins, fastlane, fastlane-match

I have problem with fastlane using Jenkins.

> **Runing this command in terminal works `fastlane provide_crashlytics_build testing:false check_xcode:false --env xxx`, but from Jenkins not working**

Error message:

```
There are no local code signing identities found.
You can run `security find-identity -v -p codesigning` to get this output.
This Stack Overflow thread has more information: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35390072/774.
(Check in Keychain Access for an expired WWDR certificate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35409835/774 has more info.)
[14:03:30]: No certificates for filter: Certificate ID: '7D72F7MC75' 
[14:03:30]: something bad happened: Could not find a matching code signing identity for type 'AdHoc'.
```

fastlane version 2.141.0

Tracing steps:

1. I run this command `security find-identity -v -p codesigning`
   and here is the result: `2 valid identities found`
2. I checked Apple Worldwide Developer certificate and its valid and trusted
3. I checked distribution certificate in Keychain and Apple Developer account and both are there

Here is Jenkins Execute Shell:

```
#!/bin/zsh
export TERM=xterm-256color
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

source /Users/Shared/Jenkins/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm use 2.6.3

fastlane provide_crashlytics_build testing:false check_xcode:false --env xxx
```

Here is faslane lane:

```
########## Upload testbuild to crashlytics ##########
  desc "Upload testbuild to crashlytics"
  lane :provide_crashlytics_build do |options|

    if options[:check_xcode]
      verify_xcode
    end

    if options[:add_badge]
        if ENV['DARK_BADGE']
        badge(dark: true)
        else
        badge
        end
    end

    build_preparations

    if options[:testing]
      start_tests
    end

    pem

    match(
      type: "adhoc",
      app_identifier: [ENV['APP_IDENTIFIER'], ENV['APP_NOTIFICATION_EXTENSION_IDENTIFIER']],
      force_for_new_devices: true
    )

    gym(
      xcargs: "ARCHIVE=NO",
      output_name: "#{ENV['OUTPUT_NAME_TESTING']}"
    )

    verify_build(
      provisioning_type: 'distribution',
      bundle_identifier: ENV['APP_IDENTIFIER']
    )

    version = get_ipa_info_plist_value(ipa: "#{ENV['OUTPUT_NAME_TESTING']}.ipa", key: "CFBundleShortVersionString")

    crashlytics(
      api_token: ENV['CRASHLYTICS_API_TOKEN'],
      build_secret: ENV['CRASHLYTICS_BUILD_SECRET'],
      emails: ENV['CRASHLYTICS_EMAILS'],
      notifications: false,
      notes: "#{change_log_last_five_commits}"
    )

    if ENV['SLACK_URL']
      sh ("say 'Yippee! What a awsome day. Thanks to #{lastCommitAuthor} something great happend. A new build is born.'")  

      slack(
        message: "New crashlytics build of #{ENV['SCHEME']} v.#{version}(#{build})",
        channel: "#{ENV['SLACK_CHANNEL']}",
        success: true,
        use_webhook_configured_username_and_icon: true,
        default_payloads: [],
        payload: {
          'Release Notes' => change_log_last_five_commits
        }
      )
    end

    clean_build_artifacts
  end
```

Here are fastlane logs:

```
Summary for match 2.141.0                                              |
+----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| type                       | adhoc                                                                                 |
| app_identifier             | ["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.NotificationServiceExtension"] |
| force_for_new_devices      | true                                                                                  |
| readonly                   | false                                                                                 |
| generate_apple_certs       | false                                                                                 |
| skip_provisioning_profiles | false                                                                                 |
| username                   | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                                                                       |
| team_id                    | R2Q6VXW97P                                                                            |
| team_name                  | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                                                             |
| storage_mode               | git                                                                                   |
| git_url                    | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                       |
| git_branch                 | master                                                                                |
| shallow_clone              | false                                                                                 |
| clone_branch_directly      | false                                                                                 |
| keychain_name              | login.keychain                                                                        |
| force                      | false                                                                                 |
| skip_confirmation          | false                                                                                 |
| skip_docs                  | false                                                                                 |
| platform                   | ios                                                                                   |
| verbose                    | false                                                                                 |
+----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              Installed Certificate                              |
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| User ID           | R2Q6VXW97P                                                  |
| Common Name       | iPhone Distribution: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (R2Q6VXW97P) |
| Organisation Unit | R2Q6VXW97P                                                  |
| Organisation      | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                                   |
| Country           | US                                                          |
| Start Datetime    | 2020-02-04 11:56:01 UTC                                     |
| End Datetime      | 2021-02-03 11:56:01 UTC                                     |
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+


+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|                          Summary for sigh 2.141.0                          |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| app_identifier                      | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx            |
| username                            | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx            |
| force                               | false                                |
| cert_id                             | 7D72F7MC75                           |
| provisioning_name                   | match AdHoc xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
| ignore_profiles_with_different_name | true                                 |
| team_id                             | R2Q6VXW97P                           |
| team_name                           | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx            |
| platform                            | ios                                  |
| adhoc                               | true                                 |
| developer_id                        | false                                |
| development                         | false                                |
| skip_install                        | false                                |
| skip_fetch_profiles                 | false                                |
| skip_certificate_verification       | false                                |
| readonly                            | false                                |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Because the Jenkins service runs like a daemon, it cannot access the login keychain, it uses the system keychain. Please make sure that your signing certificates are in the system keychain and see if this helps your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**

1. As @Scriptable said in his comment:

> Because the Jenkins service runs like a daemon, it cannot access the login keychain, it uses the system keychain. Please make sure that your signing certificates are in the system keychain and see if this helps your issue.

2. Certificate is never ever set as **Always Trust**, it must be **Use System Default**

[image]